# std::hash for unique ptr in unordered map

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, stdhash

I'm trying to hold a polymorphic type as a key in a map.

I came up with the following two structures:

Note that `Game` is an abstract class and the data structure I use is :

```
std::unordered_map<gamePtr,int> _allGames;
```

while `gamePtr` is a `typedef` for:

```
unique_ptr<Game>

template<>
struct std::hash<std::unique_ptr<Game>> {
  size_t operator()(std::unique_ptr<Game> game) const {
    return (std::hash<string>()(std::to_string(game->firstTeamFinalScore()) + game->firstTeam() + game->secondTeam()));
  }

};

struct cmp_games {
  bool operator() (std::unique_ptr<Game> game1, std::unique_ptr<Game> game2) const {  
    return *game1 == *game2;
  }
};
```

The `cmp_games` comparator seems to work fine but the `std::hash` does not because it tries to copy a `unique_ptr` (Which is ofc impossible) and I've no idea how to get over it.
Would love to hear some suggestions (If that is even possible).

EDIT: The comparator also doesn't seem to work properly. how do I make this map work correctly with `unique_ptr` as a key?

EDIT2:

Came up with:

```
template<>
struct std::hash<std::unique_ptr<Game>> {
size_t operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Game>& game) const {
     return (std::hash<string>()(std::to_string(game->firstTeamFinalScore()) + game->firstTeam() + game->secondTeam()));
}
};

template<>
struct std::equal_to<std::unique_ptr<Game>> {
bool operator() (const std::unique_ptr<Game>& game1,const std::unique_ptr<Game>& game2) const {

    return *game1 == *game2;
}

};
```

Should they be enough?

Comment: Pass the `unique_ptr` by reference to `operator()`?

Comment: Isn't `std::hash` defined for `std::unique_ptr` by the Standard anyway? It's on cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/hash

Comment: @jogojapan It seems to me that the standard hash hashes by the pointer address while the questioner wants to hash by the object's value the pointer points to, see their `cmp_games` implementation.

Comment: @Nabla Oh sure, what I mean is just that the implementation in the Standard library may provide insight into how to pass the `unique_ptr` argument. It must definitely be possible (and yes, using references is a good candidate).

Comment: What's the problem with the comperator? Please explain in what respect the *comparator also doesn't seem to work properly*?

Comment: It seems that the 3rd parameter for unordered map is a hash while the 4th is a comparator. Question is how do I pass the comparator as a 4th argument without passing the 3rd? maybe a default value for the hash?

Comment: @Rouki You don't need to provide either the 3rd or the 4th template arguments explicitly if you follow the advice in either answer below

Comment: I agree about the hash one. but what about the compare? Can I also define a specialization for the comparator? and if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, the default value for the hash. And that's`std::hash<unique_ptr<Game>>`.

Comment: Edited the question with the things Ive done

Comment: @Rouki I've updated my answer with the required comparison operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard [provides a specilization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/hash) so that `std::hash<unique_ptr<T>>` is the same as `std::hash<T*>`. So provide a specialization for `std::hash<Game *>`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdlib>

struct foo 
{
    foo(unsigned i) : i(i) {}
    unsigned i;
};

namespace std {

template<>
struct hash<foo *>
{
    size_t operator()(foo const *f) const
    {
        std::cout << "Hashing foo: " << f->i << '\n';
        return f->i;;
    }
};

}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::unique_ptr<foo>, int> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo(10)), 100));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo(20)), 200));
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f1b13f7af58d604)

---

Another option is to change your existing `std::hash` specialization so that it takes the `unique_ptr` by reference.

```
size_t operator()(std::unique_ptr<Game> const& game) const
//                                      ^^^^^^ no more copying
```

**EDIT:** `std::unique_ptr` provides [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp) that compare the managed pointers. If you want the `unordered_map` to test the `Game` objects themselves for equality, provide an `operator==` overload instead of specializing `std::equal_to`

```
inline bool operator==(const std::unique_ptr<Game>& game1, 
                       const std::unique_ptr<Game>& game2) 
{
    return *game1 == *game2;
}
```

This, in turn, requires that you've provided an equality operator for `Game` (or you could just add the logic to the function above).

```
inline bool operator==(Game const& game1, Game const& game2)
{
    return // however you want to compare these
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `game` by const reference into `std::hash::operator()`:

```
template<>
struct std::hash<std::unique_ptr<Game>> {
    size_t operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Game>& game) const;
}
```

The same applies to `cmp_games::operator()`.